# Iniciar Wildfly em modo debug

Tags: debug, cmd, wildfly

Iniciar o `Wildfly` no `eclipse` em modo `debug` é simples. Eu quero iniciar via linha de comando executando o `standalone.bat`. Até aí tudo bem, porém eu quero iniciar em modo `debug` e em condições normais eu posso abrir meu `cmd` e rodar o comando:

```
standalone.bat --debug
```

Porém é um pouco cômodo ter que abrir o `cmd` para isso. Tem como eu abrir este arquivo e colocar alguma configuração para que sendo assim eu simplesmente dê 2 cliques no arquivo para iniciá-lo em modo `debug` ?

Answer (score 1):

Basta editar o arquivo e em:

```
if "%~1" == "" (
   goto MAIN
) else if "%~1" == "--debug" (
   goto READ-DEBUG-PORT
) else if "%~1" == "-secmgr" (
   set SECMGR=true
)
```

Trocar para:

```
if "%~1" == "" (
   goto READ-DEBUG-PORT
) else if "%~1" == "--debug" (
   goto READ-DEBUG-PORT
) else if "%~1" == "-secmgr" (
   set SECMGR=true
)
```

Dessa forma ele configura para `debug` passando ou não a `flag`

---

Ababei por analisar melhor o arquivo, há uma maneira mais fácil, logo no início do arquivo há uma linha com o conteúdo `set DEBUG_MODE=false`, basta definir `DEBUG_MODE` como `true`, o efeito é exatamente o mesmo, mas requer menos alterações no arquivo e provavelmente é o correto para esse propósito.

Comment: Ele parece não estar indo ainda.

Comment: Fiz o teste com as duas maneiras, ambas ele apresenta a mensagem `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787`

Comment: Pra mim também, mas na prática não vai, posso estar fazendo algo errado mas é um teste simples de tela JSF.

Comment: Abaixo de `set DEBUG_MODE` há também `set DEBUG_PORT`, você pode configurar a porta de depuração nessa variável também